# R: Calculating the sum of rows with the function apply

Tags: r

I have this matrix `mat=matrix(rnorm(15), 1, 15)` [1x15] and I want to use the function `apply` to calculate the sum of rows in matix `mat`
e.g.

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    0  #the sum is then 6
```

Here is my code:

```
mat=matrix(rnorm(15), 1, 15)
apply(mat[,1:15],1,sum)
```

Here is the error: **Error in apply(mat[, 1:15], 1, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length**

If I create two or more rows the `apply` function works. 
e.g.

```
mat=matrix(rnorm(15), 2, 15)
apply(mat[,1:15],1,sum) #this will work
```

What should I change to the function so it would work even for matrices with one row?

Comment: So why not just `rowSums(mat)`? `rowSums` is highly optimised, and faster than `apply(..., 1, sum)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call the elements 1 to 15 you are converting your matrix to a vector so it doesn't have any dimension. just using the `as.matrix` in the apply call will make it work.

```
mat=matrix(rnorm(15), 1, 15)
apply(as.matrix(mat[,1:15]),2,sum)
```

Comment: I used `as.matrix` as you wrote but then instead of getting one value (*the sum of the row*) I get the same matrix again, and no sum

Comment: @Ville my mistake change 1 in the apply function for 2

Comment: Yes, I used a 1, but still the result is the same

Comment: Excatly change the 1 for 2, i change the code and it works as you want

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead and then go read the `?Extract` help page. That page has a wealth of information about the most fundamental functions of R, namely "[" and "[[".

```
apply(mat[ ,1:15, drop=FALSE],1,sum)  # preserves the matrix class
[1] -1.621488
```

Comment: could you explain the ` in the matrix? i have never seen that

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade - it's a typo I believe

Comment: that would make sense

Comment: Yes, typo. fixed

Answer (score 0):

create a matrix and use general apply formulation:
matrix =m, MARGIN = 1 (for row),2(for column), and FUN = sum.

```
   m=matrix(1:9,3,3)
   apply(m,1,sum)
```